# Azure build pipelines - need to know the complete path where the build logs are stored on the Microsoft Hosted Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, cicd, build-pipeline, microsoft-agent

I have a build pipeline and I need to download the logs generated from the build pipeline and save to some location in my repo. I need to know where these logs are stored on a Microsoft hosted agent from where I can copy to a path in my repos. Also, I don't want to use the below REST API to get the build logs -

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds/%7BbuildId%7D/logs?api-version=5.1)

Comment: do you want to do it during the pipeline?

Comment: yes..in the last task in the pipeline.

Comment: May I know why you don't want to use the rest api in your question?

Comment: Reason being that to make that api call in the yaml based build pipeline in DevOps looks like a task in itself where I need to take care of authentication and other aspects. Then copying the response from the REST API to some path in the Azure Repos would be another task. I wanted to keep it simple like a copy task that copies from Microsoft's agent logs path to my Azure repo